# Asking about a possibility of a genre

Tags: genre

Can I mix science-fiction and history in a story? I mean a story that is based in historical events with a touch of science fiction, is that possible or am I trying to invent something "ridiculous"

Comment: Given that it has been done several hundred times in the past, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can also write a story about someone travelling in time to some past era and interacting with historical or legendary persons.

One of the earliest examples is Mark Twain's *A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court* (1889).

Examples by mainstream authors include *The Sense of the Past*, 1917, by Henry James, a partial inspiration for the play *Berkeley Square*, 1926, which had several movie versions.

When science fiction became a genre in the 20th century a sub genre of time travel stories involving technological time travel to the future or to prehistoric or historic past eras developed.  Various science fiction stories developed rules (valid only in the stories they were used in) about how time travel works and whether people can change the past or not, and whther there will be "grandfather paraxdoxes" if they change even the slightest event in history.

Souces about time travel in science fiction would be very useful for someone writing such a story.

And another type of historical/science fiction blend is a story set in an historical era where events happen differently than history claims.  What if aliens really helped build the pyarmids?  What if some of the people in history with allegedly nonhuman ancestry actually did have supernatural or alien ancestors?  And so on.

Answer (score 6):

It's called Alt-History and it's not something new.
Just make sure that if you write it over a longer time frame (like if your story starts in the 30's and goes up to the 70's) that it will be a different 70's then we had due tot he changes you made in the 30's.

Most common ones are Alt histories about WW1 and WW2 where the Central Powers or the Axis got a technological boost that helped them win the war.

These can range from serious, like Nazi's inventing Nukes before the allies.
or a bit more ridiculous like WW1 Germans riding machinegun mounted dinosaurs.

Comment: If your story takes place in the 19th century, it could be part of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk genre.